# Fastest loading: Redirect with header location in PHP, or Rewrite with Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, redirect, redirection, 301-redirect

after becoming aware of the major lag that hits my site becaouse of the homepage redirect, i read into numerous optimization threads, proving that a 301 redirect slams out approximately 100ms to a staggering 400ms out of the total load time. On my website its around 250ms. Silly i know! On the other hand i really *do* need a redirect to the default language, because other domains for the different languages. What i have works, but wastest 250ms every single time.

**Is there anyway this can done be faster?**
Through htaccess rewrite perhaps?

**CURRENTLY HAVE** index.php

```
<?php
switch($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]){
case "site.org":
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: /en/home');   # extensio .php is hidden: 'home' is a file

case "site.fr":
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: /fr/home');   # extensio .php is hidden: 'home' is a file
etc etc
?>
```

**I HAVE TRIED**
Simply including `home` that works for the first homepage beautifully, ***BUT*** the url in the browser is in this way NOT set to `site.org/en/home` you just see the `site.org` and all links then dont work anymore. What i need is that the homepage loads AND the url in the browser becomes `/xx/home`

Any and all clues are very appreciated +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without checking myself, I would guess that you'll see a performance increase by using mod_rewrite, because that way Apache isn't having to invoke PHP, which in turn isn't having to parse and then execute your code.

What you probably want is something like this:-

```
# Check for site.org/
RewriteCond       %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/$
RewriteCond       %{HTTP_HOST}     ^site.org$
RewriteRule       ^/$              /en/home         [RL]

# Check for site.fr/
RewriteCond       %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/$
RewriteCond       %{HTTP_HOST}     ^site.fr$
RewriteRule       ^/$              /fr/home         [RL]
```

This is off the top of my head, so it's probably not completely correct, but hopefully it'll give you a good idea of what you can do. The documentation for mod_rewrite is pretty good, and it's at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html.

Comment: Thanks Andy, +1, this sounds more familiar to me. i like the code layout! keeps things neat. Is this faster than Virtual host method that ms has suggested. Gave it a try but helas: errors and nothing loads.. Log file says doesnt know that flag [RL] on Apache/2.0.54 (Fedora). Any idea who to get this redirect to work?

Comment: Sorry Sam - the [RL] should be [R,L] - in my defence it was quite late ;-)

Comment: Just noticed as well that my original idea would redirect site.org to site.org/en/home, and site.fr to site.fr/fr/home. If you change the second field of the RewriteRule lines to http://site.org/en/home and http://site.org/fr/home, it'll be a bit neater. Speedwise it should be the same as ms's suggestion - they're both using mod_rewrite so it's being handled within Apache itself.

Answer (score 3):

Another (probably the fastest from web server perspective) way is to use Apache VirtualHosts with `RedirectPermament` directive

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.site.org
ServerAlias site.org *.site.org
<LocationMatch "^/$">
RedirectPermanent /en/home
</LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.site.fr
ServerAlias site.fr *.site.fr
<LocationMatch "^/$">
RedirectPermanent /fr/home
</LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks MS, +1, sounds too good to be true, on shared hosting with plesk 8.2 and usual privileges? Will give it a try now.

Comment: You canot use Virtual Hosts in .htaccess. It should be placed in `server config` context. In htaccess you could use mod_rewrite, as Andy suggested.